# How to check textual user input in a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: powerpoint, user-input

Is it possible to check textual user input in a PowerPoint presentation?
I would like to create some kind of password field that users need the fill in correctly, before they can move on to the next slide.

To be clear: This is while the presentation is running, not in the edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

An ActiveX text box can receive user input while the presentation is in slideshow view and has a Password Character property which, if set, displays the chosen character instead of whatever the user is typing; keeps the password safe from prying eyes.

Comment: Can the input then also be checked to see if the password is correct? To decided to go the the next slide or not, for example?

Comment: Yes. There's an example of retrieving the text from an ActiveX text box here: https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00772_Show_me_the_text_in_an_ActiveX_-_OLE_text_control_on_a_slide.htm  The relevant bit: assuming you have a reference to the text box in the variable oTextBox, you can retrieve the text with oTextBox.OLEFormat.Object.Text